# How do I get a WMI subscriber to run from a script?

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am trying to register a WMI event handler from inside a Powershell script file.

Here is the complete script I'm testing with.

```
$RegPath = 'HKCU:\Test\'
$Query = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PnPEntity'"
Register-WmiEvent -Query $Query -SourceIdentifier "Handler" -Action { Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegPath -Name 'test' -Value '1'}
```

It does require a new registry key to be setup before running the script. At the `HKCU`, the `Test` key needs to be created. The event handler adds the `test` property to this key and gives it a value. To test the script, I delete the `test` property and plug any USB device into the computer.

When I paste the three lines into a Powershell terminal and plug in a USB device, it writes the `test` property. If I save the three commands to a `ps1` file, open a Powershell terminal and run the script from there, it never writes the property. Running `Get-EventSubscriber` shows the handler is still registered after the script finishes.

I also tried to add a loop to force the script to stay open. Pasting the commands in and adding the while loop writes the property to registry. The script never closes, but also doesn't write the property to the registry.

```
while ($true) {
    start-sleep -seconds 1
}
```

Any ideas? Could it be a permission issue?

PS Version.

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                                                 
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.3031                                                                                        
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                               
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                               
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.3031                                                                                       
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                       
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                   
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                   
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: You need an event consumer. Check out the answer here for an example using `ActiveScriptEventConsumer` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36886123/7411885, or the other types of consumers here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/monitoring-and-responding-to-events-with-standard-consumers

Comment: `Register-WmiEvent` works perfectly unless it's called from a script. I'm not looking to run anything other than the one `Set-ItemProperty` command. Is `ActiveScriptEventConsumer` an alternative to `Register-WmiEvent`? Importantly, I cannot have the handler be permanent, which is a requirement of the question you linked. I choose `Register-WmiEvent` specifically because it drops off when the terminal session ends.

Comment: Ah yeah I misunderstood the problem. I'll test, but it could just be a scope issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [scoping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes) issue. When you run it as a script, `$RegPath` only exists within the local scope of that script, while the event subscriber gets created in a separate session. The  `Action` job seems to inherit your current interactive session, where `$RegPath` is not set. You can see the error when you check the job output:

```
Get-Job 'Handler' | select Id,Name,Error

Id Name    Error
-- ----    -----
 1 Handler {Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.}
```

---

The easy fix is to set the path statically:

```
Register-WmiEvent -Action { Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Test\' -Name 'test' -Value '1'} -Query $Query -SourceIdentifier "Handler"
```

Or if it must be a variable, create that variable inside of the job action script block:

```
Register-WmiEvent -Query $Query -SourceIdentifier "Handler" -Action { 
  $RegPath = 'HKCU:\Test\'
  Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegPath -Name 'test' -Value '1'
}
```

---

There are [some](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/register-wmievent?view=powershell-5.1) automatic variables you can use for these that pull from the event itself: `$Event`, `$EventSubscriber`, `$Sender`, `$EventArgs`, and `$Args`.

I also recommend you use [Register-CimIndicationEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/register-cimindicationevent?view=powershell-5.1) instead of `Register-WmiEvent`. They are fully interchangeable, but `Register-WMIEvent` was removed in newer versions of powershell.

Comment: You were right about it being a scope issue. I heard about the cim move from some other questions I looked at, but documentation for anything about the wmi system is hard to find. I assume the scoping issue would still apply to `Register-CimIndicationEvent` as it sounds like a Powershell feature.

Comment: That's correct. Both commands create a `BackgroundJob` where your `-Action` script runs like a child process. See more about how they behave here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_jobs